# Difference between yield in Python and yield in C#

Tags: c#, python

What is the difference between `yield` keyword in Python and `yield` keyword in C#?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

C#'s `yield return` is equivalent to Python's `yield` , and `yield break` is just `return` in Python.

Other than those minor differences, they have basically the same purpose.

Comment: yield break in C# is not exactly equivalent to Python's return. If your function does nothing except yield break( return in Python), you will get a empty Enumerator while a None in python.

Comment: That's a minor syntactic quirk of Python; you can use `return; yield` to get an empty generator.

Comment: Also `yield` in Python is an expression that can receive values from the iterating site. `yield return` is a statement.

Comment: But NO yield from in C# which is very sad. To emulate similar behaviour, there's a lot of boilerplate code which can't be put into a function. **EDIT:** If you're using Unity, it does have nested coroutines!

Answer (score 15):

The most important difference is that python yield gives you an iterator, once it is fully iterated that's over.

But C# yield return gives you an iterator "**factory"**, which you can pass it around and uses it in multiple places of your code without concerning whether it has been "looped" once before.

Take this example in python:

```
In [235]: def func1():
   .....:     for i in xrange(3):
   .....:         yield i
   .....:

In [236]: x1 = func1()

In [237]: for k in x1:
   .....:     print k
   .....:
0
1
2

In [238]: for k in x1:
   .....:     print k
   .....:

In [239]:
```

And in C#:

```
class Program
{
    static IEnumerable<int> Func1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            yield return i;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x1 = Func1();
        foreach (int k in x1) 
            Console.WriteLine(k);

        foreach (int k in x1)
            Console.WriteLine(k);
    }
}
```

That gives you:

```
0
1
2
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 1):

An important distinction to note, in addition to other answers, is that `yield` in C# can't be used as an expression, only as a statement.

An example of `yield` expression usage in Python (example pasted from [here](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/yieldexpr.html)):

```
def echo(value=None):
  print "Execution starts when 'next()' is called for the first time."
  try:
    while True:
       try:
         value = (yield value)
       except GeneratorExit:
         # never catch GeneratorExit
         raise
       except Exception, e:
         value = e
     finally:
       print "Don't forget to clean up when 'close()' is called."

generator = echo(1)
print generator.next()
# Execution starts when 'next()' is called for the first time.
# prints 1

print generator.next()
# prints None

print generator.send(2)
# prints 2

generator.throw(TypeError, "spam")
# throws TypeError('spam',)

generator.close()
# prints "Don't forget to clean up when 'close()' is called."
```

Comment: But from your link expression usage is only beneficial for generators, which would appear to be achievable in C# via a call to `GetEnumerator` on the resulting `IEnumerable<T>` you would return from yielding method.

Comment: @KennethK. I'm not disproving that in my answer in any way. The question asked about differences in `yield` keyword, not the differences in how returned generator/iterator objects may be treated

Comment: I don't disagree, but your argument is "there is no yield expression in C#" to which one might resolve, "then I can't do the same thing in C# that I can do in Python", but that doesn't seem to be the case. The fact that C# can't do expression-yields doesn't mean you can't achieve the same functionality (unless I misunderstand the Python functionality, which is certainly possible since Python isn't my forte).

Comment: As far as I understand, even when you're able to call `GetEnumerator` on the result, you won't be able to pass values into the generator function, which is what `yield` expression evaluates in Python version. There is no method on `IEnumerator` interface that matches the semantics of Python's `send()` generator method.

Comment: OK, I understand what you're saying now.