# yield break in Python

Tags: python, generator, yield

According to answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704607/difference-between-yield-in-python-and-yield-in-c), `yield break` in C# is equivalent to `return` in Python. In the normal case, `return` indeed stops a generator. But if your function does nothing but `return`, you will get a `None` not an empty iterator, which is returned by `yield break` in C#

```
def generate_nothing():
    return

for i in generate_nothing():
    print i
```

You will get a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`,
but if I add and never run `yield` before `return`, this function returns what I expect.

```
def generate_nothing():
    if False: yield None
    return
```

It works, but seems weird. Do you have a better idea?

Comment: That's just how Python works. I don't think you really even need the final `return` in there. Python is not C#. don't expect them to work the same.

Comment: A function without `yield` is not a generator. Thus your first example just returns `None` and tries to iterate over that.

Comment: @Jochen: that's not a generator. It's an iterable-producing object. Though as I said in phihag's answer, it's unlikely to matter.

Answer (score 67):

```
def generate_nothing():
    return
    yield
```

Comment: This will create an code is unreachable warning in linters though.

Comment: @congusbongus Usually you want to break from generator given some condition and so use `if <condition>: return` instead of bare `return`.

Answer (score 52):

A good way to handle this is raising [StopIteration](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration) which is what is raised when your iterator has nothing left to yield and `next()` is called. This will also gracefully break out of a for loop with nothing inside the loop executed.

For example, given a tuple `(0, 1, 2, 3)` I want to get overlapping pairs `((0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3))`. I could do it like so:

```
def pairs(numbers):
    if len(numbers) < 2:
        raise StopIteration

    for i, number in enumerate(numbers[1:]):
        yield numbers[i], number
```

Now `pairs` safely handles lists with 1 number or less.

Comment: note that from vs 3.6 and on this is a bad idea because with the implementation of [PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/) the `StopIteration` will be converted into a `RuntimeError` to prevent problems when using sub generators.

Comment: It's a bad idea in any version; just `return`.

Comment: While this is functional (for now), `return` is better; the described functionality is even included in the [return documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement).

Answer (score 10):

```
def generate_nothing():
    return iter([])
```

Comment: or `xrange(0)` (`range(0)` in 3.x).

Comment: Both of these are about twice as fast as `return; yield`. But be aware that these will return objects of types `<type 'listiterator'>` and `<type 'xrange'>`, both of which are direct subtypes of `object` - so they are not generators. Not that that's likely to matter. Merely of academic interest :-)

Comment: @Chris: in python3, I'm only clocking it about 20-30% faster, though qualitatively it seems slightly less of a strain of memory (not a rigorous test: `z=[list(f()) for _ in range(10**7)]`)

Answer (score 4):

The funny part is that both functions have the same bytecode. Probably there's a flag that sets to `generator` when bytecode compiler finds the `yield` keyword.

```
>>> def f():
...   return

>>> def g():
...   if False: yield 
#in Python2 you can use 0 instead of False to achieve the same result


>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(f)
2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
            3 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis(g)
2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
            3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Huh? They're far from the same. Check your results again. You made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @Chris Yeah, Python2 don't optimize it because False isn't a keyword and might not be a false value. Python3 does.

Comment: Sweet. It doesn't even generates bytecode for yield statement

Comment: @JBernado: hmm, I see that that is possible in Python 3. I was thinking at first that that would be a glaring problem if False was assigned a different value. I'd forgotten that `True` and `False` are keywords in Python 3. And with the same bytecode, I presume the difference is in the fact that `f.__code__.co_flags == 67` while `g.__code__.co_flags == 99`. That suggests to be that the sixth bit flag marks it as a generator. Apologies for criticising you - but you really should mark it as Python 3 now for producing the same byte code, anyway.

Comment: @Chris I had already made a comment in my answer :) In Python 2 you can use 0 instead of False