# How to make Python recognize a function as a generator function?

Tags: python, generator, yield

First, consider the following code (I'm going to discuss several versions of `subgen()` next):

```
>>> def maingen(i):
...    print("maingen started")
...    yield from subgen(i)
...    print("maingen finished")
...
>>> for i in maingen(5):
...     print(i)
...
```

I want to write several `subgen` generator functions.

A normal one is:

```
>>> def subgen_1(i):
...     yield i + 1
...     yield i + 2
...     yield i + 3
```

No prob, output is as expected:

```
maingen started
6
7
8
maingen finished
```

Now, I want an other version of `subgen` *which yields nothing*...

If I try that:

```
>>> def subgen_2(i):
...     i * 3
```

I've an exception:

```
maingen started
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

It's expected: `subgen_2` isn't a generator function.

OK, next. I can read somewhere (like the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395063/yield-break-in-python))
that I've to raise a `StopIteration`. (Note that, as a newbie, I can't comment this answer.)

```
>>> def subgen_3(i):
...     i * 3
...     raise StopIteration()
...
```

As identified in [PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/), *"Finally, the proposal also clears up the confusion about how to terminate a generator: the proper way is `return`, not raise `StopIteration`."*, I only get:

```
maingen started
```

(no `maingen finished`...)

And the only way I've found to get things OK is:

```
>>> def subgen_4(i):
...     i * 3
...     return
...     yield
...
```

With this, I get:

```
maingen started
maingen finished
```

Hourrah! But this solution isn't beautiful...

**Does anyone have a better or a more pythonic idea?**

**Is it possible to write a decorator to secretly add the ugly yield statement?**

Comment: a function could return a generator without necessarily being a generator itself, you could just `return iter([])` if you want the function to run and then result in an empty iterator.

Comment: if `subgen_2` does not actually `yield` anything why do you use `yield from subgen_2()` in the first place?

Comment: That answer you linked to only mentioned raising a `StopIteration` to stop the generator (without yielding anything first). It does not change the fact though, that you need to have a `yield` statement in the function body (syntactically), to make it a generator function.

Comment: use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6395075/5827215) or poke's idea of `yield from []`, in any case you are asking how to make an empty generator which is exactly the same as [yield break in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395063/yield-break-in-python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading all comments, I think the more *pythonic* way is to rewrite the `maingen`:

```
def maingen(i):
    print("maingen started")
    gen = subgen(i)
    if gen:
        yield from gen
    print("maingen finished")
```

With that, a `subgen` which is really a generator function:

```
def subgen_1(i):
    yield i + 1
    yield i + 2
    yield i + 3
```

or a `subgen` which is a simple function:

```
def subgen_2(i):
    i * 3
```

are both "accepted" when "injected" in the `maingen` generator function, and don't need some ugly `yield` statements.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a sub generator to yield nothing, then return an empty iterator:

```
def subgen_2(i):
    i * 3
    return iter([]) #empty iterator
```

The reason you were getting `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` is because without a `yield` statement in your sub-generator it was not a generator, but a regular function that implicitly returned `None`.

By returning a valid iterator that doesn't produce any values you will be able to `yield from subgen_2()` without error and without generating any additional values.

Another way to hide this (I don't really see why you would want to) is to make a decorator that literally just calls your function then does `return iter(())` or `yield from []`.

```
def gen_nothing(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args,**kw):
        f(*args,**kw)
        yield from []
    return wrapper
```

But the only difference this produces is that the stack will require one additional frame for the wrapper, which means your Traceback messages will have a bit more noise:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Tadhg/Documents/codes/test.py", line 15, in <module>
    for i in subgen():
  File "/Users/Tadhg/Documents/codes/test.py", line 6, in wrapper
    f(*args,**kw)
  File "/Users/Tadhg/Documents/codes/test.py", line 12, in subgen
    3/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: Since `return iter([])` does not turn the function into a generator itself, and you might prefer that, you can use something like `yield from []` to do the equivalent thing and produce a generator function instead.

Comment: I was asking for a more beautiful way... The `yield from []` solution is a good one.

Comment: But I was also asking if it's possible to write a decorator to hide that "fake" statement...

Comment: Thanks. I'm not a fan too... And I just posted an answer to show how I prefer to rewrite the `maingen` generator function.